# What are best practices for web development source code version control?

Tags: version-control

I have a few simple websites that get updated via ftp.  My issue here is that I have no version control.  If I utilize github, I would have to synchronize my local files, with my remote ftp, and also my github. Sounds messy.  Is there a better approach to my madness.  Ideally, I'd like to have source control (github) with any automatic publish to ftp.  Does this exist?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use some continuous integration server ( http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html )?
Then you could configure it to publish to wherever you like on a click of a button or automatically after every commit when automatic tests don't fail.
There are many CI servers

CruiseControl (.NET) - http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/

TeamCity - http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html?gclid=CPjku5iTsawCFU5TfAodfWMWGA

Jenkins (formerly known as Hudson) - http://hudson-ci.org/

I don't think there is/should be anything specyfic to web development when it comes to source control. I use CI for every kind of development.

Answer (score 0):

- Assembla with github-repo integration and FTP-tool
- Git hooks on **local Git**, which can (post-commit hook, f.e) push to Github and upload to FTP *automagically*